# Rotation angle of the composition of two reflections in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have the following problem that I can only partially solve: We are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $v_1,v_2$ be two normed (of length 1) and linearly independent vectors. Let $R_i,\ i\in \{1,2\}$ be the two reflections on $\langle v_i\rangle ^\perp$ i.e. $S|_{\langle v_i\rangle}=-\text{id},\ S|_{\langle v_i\rangle^\perp}=\text{id}$.

Show the following:

1. $S_1S_2$ is a rotation
2. The rotation axis is $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle^\perp$
3. The rotation angle is $\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=\pm (v_1,v_2)$ where $(v_1,v_2)$ denotes the inner product of these vectors.

**My attempt:** I am fairly certain that I have gotten the first two correct: As each reflection is orthogonal and $O(3)$ is a group, their product $S_1S_2\in O(3)$. Furthermore, the determinant of a reflection is -1 and, thus $S_1S_2\in SO(3)$ is a rotation.

I have also been able to show the rotation axis: As, for something to be the rotation axis, it has to be the eigenvector of the eigenvalue 1. That is $(S_1S_2-id)(w)= S_1S_2(w)-id(w)=w-w=0$ for any $w\in \langle v_1,v_2\rangle^\perp$. Implying that $\langle w\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle^\perp$ is indeed the rotation axis.

It is the third part I am struggling on. I should perhaps mention that I know that the rotation angle $\alpha$ of any rotational matrix is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(tr(A)-1)=\cos\alpha$. However, I am not able to progress from here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you have a fixed axis, the plane orthogonal to this axis is stable. This plane is $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$. Can you see what the restriction of your rotation to this plane is ? (Hint : $S_1$ and $S_2$ both fix the axis)

Comment: Do you mean to say that the restricition is the identity on this plane?

Comment: No, if it was the identity, since it is already the identity on the orthogonal axis, the rotation would be the identity. What I mean is that all your transformations fix the orthogonal axis and preserve this plane, so if you understand their restriction to this plane (which is easier, since it is of dimension 2), you understand them completely (by taking the direct sum with the fixed line)